# Why Webpack includes all files from a subdirectory?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm following [Angular i18n guide for JIT compiler](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-jit-compiler) and it has next code to support multiple languages

```
const translations = require(`raw-loader!./locale/${devLocale}.xlf`);
```

Where `devLocale` is defined based on URL.

Now, when I look into my bundle I see all .xlf files imported

```
/***/ "./node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!./src/i18n/de.xlf":
...
/***/ "./node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!./src/i18n/fr.xlf":
```

It looks like Webpack scans that folder and includes all the files. It's completely magic for me. Which part does that? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

well, so that's a result of this behaviour https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression

all files that match a require pattern are included in the bundle